# Passing wildcards into List.indexOf() in Java possible?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

As an example, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Arrays.asList(Serial.list()).indexOf("/dev/tty.usbmodem*");
```

Is this possible? Or what is the proper method for accomplishing this. It would be fine if it returns the first element of match, as it supposed to. I suppose if there is a method, such as a grep method of some kind that returned a new array of strings that met the condition, that would be fine too.

Comment: Nope. Iterate through the list and check each one.

Comment: Or even better, since you might want to do this for various cases, write a utility method that abstracts away the looping, so that you can specify just the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a loop

```
for(String s : list() )
     if(s.startsWith("start to look for "))
           return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`indexOf(Object)` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) states that the methods returns

> the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this
>   list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

So no, you cannot do that.

I'm assuming you're trying to do this with a `List<String>`, but the interface is for all types of `List`. How would what you are trying to do work for `List<Integer>`?

You'll have to do your own iteration and pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate though the list, as other solutions point out, because the built in `indexOf` won't do this.  What would have been nice for Java to provide (and it's easy to implement), would be a version of `indexOf` that takes a predicate and returns the first element of the list satisfying the predicate.  As I said, this is pretty easy to implement in a utility class, though.  Here's a simple version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class StringUtil {

    interface Predicate<T> {
        boolean test( T object );
    }

    public static <T> int indexOf( final List<T> list, final Predicate<T> predicate ) { 
        final Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
        for ( int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++ ) {
            if ( predicate.test( it.next() )) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final List<String> list = Arrays.asList( "foo", "bar", "baz" );

        // Find the index of the first string that starts with "ba".
        final int index = indexOf( list, new Predicate<String>() {
            public boolean test( final String string ) {
                return string.startsWith( "ba" );
            }
        });

        // It's 1 (for "bar").
        System.out.println( index );
    }
}
```